# Zend 2 Cannot connect to Database

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am using wamp server with MySQL for writing my first zend 2 application.

I have the following problem:

```
Message:
Connect Error: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'kljpeer'
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Git\klj-website\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo.php(249): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Connection->connect()
#1 D:\Git\klj-website\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\Sql\Sql.php(120): Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\Pdo\Pdo->createStatement()
#2 D:\Git\klj-website\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(232): Zend\Db\Sql\Sql->prepareStatementForSqlObject(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#3 D:\Git\klj-website\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(208): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->executeSelect(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#4 D:\Git\klj-website\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway.php(195): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->selectWith(Object(Zend\Db\Sql\Select))
#5 D:\Git\klj-website\module\Website\src\Website\Model\PostTable.php(24): Zend\Db\TableGateway\AbstractTableGateway->select()
#6 D:\Git\klj-website\module\Website\src\Website\Controller\HomeController.php(23): Website\Model\PostTable->fetchAll()
#7 D:\Git\klj-website\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController.php(83): Website\Controller\HomeController->indexAction()
#8 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 D:\Git\klj-website\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 D:\Git\klj-website\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 D:\Git\klj-website\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#12 D:\Git\klj-website\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#13 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#14 D:\Git\klj-website\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#15 D:\Git\klj-website\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#16 D:\Git\klj-website\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(313): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#17 D:\Git\klj-website\public\index.php(17): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#18 {main}
```

This is my config file: global.php

```
return array(
    'db' => array(
         'driver'         => 'Pdo',
         'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=kljpeer;host=localhost',
         'driver_options' => array(
             PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES \'UTF8\''
         ),
     ),
     'service_manager' => array(
         'factories' => array(
             'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter'
                     => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
         ),
     ),
);
```

This is my config file: local.php.dist

```
return array(
     'db' => array(
         'username' => 'root',
         'password' => '',
     ),
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try rename *local.php.dist* to **local.php**

```
├───config
│   │   application.config.php
│   │
│   └───autoload
│           global.php
│           local.php   - your local settings
│
```

> Zend Framework 2’s ModuleManager merges all the configuration from
>   each module’s module.config.php file  and then merges in the files in
>   config/autoload (*.global.php and then *.local.php files)

[User Guide - Database and models](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html#using-servicemanager-to-configure-the-table-gateway-and-inject-into-the-albumtable)

e.g:

```
// global.php
 return array(
     'db' => array(
         'driver'         => 'Pdo',
         'dsn'            => 'mysql:dbname=kljpeer;host=localhost',
         ...
     ),
 );

// local.php
 return array(
     'db' => array(
         'username' => 'YOUR USERNAME HERE',
         'password' => 'YOUR PASSWORD HERE',
     ),
 );
```

Comment: how about with remote server..I was facing issue in connecting with remote server,